# How to use SSL_read() and SSL_accept() on non blocking

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, nonblocking

I have a client/server communication that needs to be upgraded to SSL communication. Currently I have a network socket that sends and receives tcp data.

1. Client issues a tcp connect() to the server.
2. Server has the accept part already implemented , after accepting the connection the server enters a select loop, awaiting further op.

what I have tried:

After the tcp connect() is complete, the fd I get is what I use for openssl SSL_set_fd(ssl,fd). While on the server side after network accept I am upgrading the connection to non blocking and doing SSL_accept , calling SSL_connect() client side which is successful ( I have taken care of all the certificate and other things needed).

What I need to undertand:

1. SSL_accept() returns -1 with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, few inputs I received suggested me to put it in a 'while' loop, waiting for the ssl accept to complete. which solves it by eventually looping over many times on the ssl_accept. The confusion is if I should loop here or go back to select loop. Going back to select loop I see that the network select pops instantly back probably due to some data present due to ssl_connect. Is this the right way?
2. I have sent X bytes on client side with SSL_write(), which is successfully sent, when the select pops with read, I am doing an SSL_read() which does the read operation but it is less than X, so I iterate again over SSL_read() only to see 0 bytes returned in successive reads. Same question here how long should I loop aroung SSL_read() and do I have to, or got to select and wait out.
3. what happens if I pass SSL_read(ssl,buf,bytes) bytes more than what was received, how to handle that

I have tried SSL_pending() after first read but it always returns 0. where as there is obviously missing data.
Client code

```
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd);

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) < 0 )
    {
        /* Log failure */
        return(-1);
    } else {

        ssl_write_return = SSL_write(ssl, msg , req_len);

        switch(SSL_get_error(ssl, ssl_write_return)) 
        {
            
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
               ...
            default:
               ... 
            SSL_free(ssl);
        }
    }
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Server code

```
 ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, session->fd);    
    while(TRUE){
            if ((ssl_accept_ret =SSL_accept(ssl)) != 1){
                
                        log ("ssl_accept failed with %d\n", ssl_accept_ret);
                switch(SSL_get_error(ssl,ssl_accept_ret )){
                    case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
                        continue;            
                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        continue;        
                    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
                }
                return(-1);
            } else {
                log ("ssl_accept was successful with %d\n", ssl_accept_ret);
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

server read code

```
while(TRUE){
            ret = SSL_read(session->ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (ret<=0){

                
                switch(SSL_get_error(session->ssl,ret)){

                    case SSL_ERROR_NONE:                       
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
                        continue;            
                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
                        continue;        
                    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                            break;
                    case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                    default:
                        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));  
                        break;
                }
                exit_select_loop()
            } else {
                
                log( "ssl_read was successful with %d and %s \n", ret,buf);
                do{
                     ret = SSL_read(session->ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
                   
                      log("ssl_read  %d and %s \n", ret,buf);
                }while(SSL_pending(session->ssl)!=0 && (SSL_get_error(session->ssl, ret) == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE || SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ));
            } 
        }
```

Comment: OpenSSL's legacy API controls the socket I/O, not you, so the tricky part about using  this API with non-blocking sockets is to NOT call `select()` until OpenSSL tells you to!  Which means NOT using a `select()` loop to drive your I/O logic.  This is the opposite of traditional non-blocking socket I/O.  If you want to use a traditional I/O model, use OpenSSL''s `BIO` API instead, so you are in full control of the socket I/O, not OpenSSL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
1. By opposite of traditional non blocking socket I/O, do you mean it is blocking I/O ?
2. If I do have to adopt BIO, it does take the SSL object as parameter so should I be doing a socket accept which has to be blocking or non blocking ?  what I mean to ask is , is bio non blocking ,thanks for the  response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a working ssl code in website, you can try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

//#include "imapfilter.h"
//#include "session.h"


#define TCP_DEFAULTBACK_LOG 15
#define HTTP_RESPON_TIMEOUT 15
//#define FORMAT_HTTPCHECK_REQ(buf,serv,port) snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf)-1,"GET /api/v1/echo/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s:%d\r\n\r\n",serv,port)
#define FORMAT_HTTPCHECK_REQ(buf,serv,port) snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf)-1,"CONNECT 192.168.1.1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s:%d\r\n\r\n",serv,port)

#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x1010000fL
SSL_CTX *sslctx = NULL;
#else
SSL_CTX *ssl23ctx = NULL;
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
SSL_CTX *ssl3ctx = NULL;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_METHOD
SSL_CTX *tls1ctx = NULL;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_1_METHOD
SSL_CTX *tls11ctx = NULL;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_METHOD
SSL_CTX *tls12ctx = NULL;
#endif
#endif



/* IMAP session. */
typedef struct session {
    int socket;     /* Socket. */
    SSL *sslconn;       /* SSL connection. */
} session;
#define error  printf

static int
open_connection(session *ssn,const char* serv,uint16_t port,const char* sslproto);
static int
close_connection(session *ssn);
static ssize_t
socket_read(session *ssn, char *buf, size_t len, long timeout, int timeoutfail, int *interrupt);
static ssize_t
socket_write(session *ssn, const char *buf, size_t len);

static int
open_secure_connection(session *ssn,const char* serv,const char* sslproto);
static int
close_secure_connection(session *ssn);
static ssize_t
socket_secure_read(session *ssn, char *buf, size_t len);
static ssize_t
socket_secure_write(session *ssn, const char *buf, size_t len);



/*
 * Connect to mail server.
 */
static int
open_connection(session *ssn,const char* serv,uint16_t port,const char* sslproto)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *ressave;
    int n, sockfd;

        char    portstr[32];
        sprintf(portstr,"%d",portstr);
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    n = getaddrinfo(serv, portstr, &hints, &res);

    if (n < 0) {
        error("gettaddrinfo; %s\n", gai_strerror(n));
        return -1;
    }

    ressave = res;

    sockfd = -1;

    while (res) {
        sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,
            res->ai_protocol);

        if (sockfd >= 0) {
            if (connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == 0)
                break;

            sockfd = -1;
        }
        res = res->ai_next;
    }

    if (ressave)
        freeaddrinfo(ressave);

    if (sockfd == -1) {
        error("error while initiating connection to %s at port %d\n",
            serv, port);
        return -1;
    }

    ssn->socket = sockfd;

    if (sslproto) {
        if (open_secure_connection(ssn,serv,sslproto) == -1) {
            close_connection(ssn);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return ssn->socket;
}


/*
 * Initialize SSL/TLS connection.
 */
static int
open_secure_connection(session *ssn,const char* serv,const char* sslproto)
{
    int r, e;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;

#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x1010000fL
    if (sslctx)
        ctx = sslctx;
#else
    if (ssl23ctx)
        ctx = ssl23ctx;

    if (sslproto) {
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
        if (ssl3ctx && !strcasecmp(sslproto, "ssl3"))
            ctx = ssl3ctx;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_METHOD
        if (tls1ctx && !strcasecmp(sslproto, "tls1"))
            ctx = tls1ctx;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_1_METHOD
        if (tls11ctx && !strcasecmp(sslproto, "tls1.1"))
            ctx = tls11ctx;
#endif
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_METHOD
        if (tls12ctx && !strcasecmp(sslproto, "tls1.2"))
            ctx = tls12ctx;
#endif
    }
#endif

    if (ctx == NULL) {
        error("initiating SSL connection to %s; protocol version "
              "not supported by current build", serv);
        goto fail;
    }

    if (!(ssn->sslconn = SSL_new(ctx)))
        goto fail;

#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x1000000fL
    r = SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssn->sslconn, serv);
    if (r == 0) {
        error("failed setting the Server Name Indication (SNI) to "
            "%s; %s\n", serv,
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        goto fail;
    }
#endif

    SSL_set_fd(ssn->sslconn, ssn->socket);

    for (;;) {
        if ((r = SSL_connect(ssn->sslconn)) > 0)
            break;

        switch (SSL_get_error(ssn->sslconn, r)) {
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            error("initiating SSL connection to %s; the "
                "connection has been closed cleanly\n",
                serv);
            goto fail;
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            e = ERR_get_error();
            if (e == 0 && r == 0)
                error("initiating SSL connection to %s; EOF in "
                    "violation of the protocol\n", serv);
            else if (e == 0 && r == -1)
                error("initiating SSL connection to %s; %s\n",
                    serv, strerror(errno));
            else
                error("initiating SSL connection to %s; %s\n",
                    serv, ERR_error_string(e, NULL));
            goto fail;
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
            error("initiating SSL connection to %s; %s\n",
                serv, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),
                NULL));
            goto fail;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    // TODO: ignore cert if (get_option_boolean("certificates") && get_cert(ssn) == -1)
    //  goto fail;

    return 0;

fail:
    ssn->sslconn = NULL;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: some SSL error not means ssl connection error, it should continue(such as SSL_ERROR_NONE、SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ、SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE ... ). So the best way is research OPENSSL api manual.  I copy the code here to point his problem which error should continue.

Comment: @RainLi this does help me understand the implementation, any idea on the select() part of things

Comment: in most case, if not send big data, write always available. select read+exception is enough.

Comment: You found this on a website, but do not give credit to what website it was.  Your post should include a reference the the site containing this code.